# React/Typescript creating custom input forwardRef

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following component

```
interface IInputProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement> {}

const Input: React.FunctionComponent<IInputProps> = React.forwardRef((props, ref: React.ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>) => {
return <input ref={ref} />;
});
```

I want to create a custom `input` where you can forward a ref to it, however I'm getting the error

```
Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<Pick<IInputProps, "key" | "accept" | "acceptCharset" | "action" | "allowFullScreen" | "allowTransparency" | "alt" | "as" | "async" | "autoComplete" | "autoFocus" | ... 348 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & RefAttributes<...>>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<IInputProps>'.
Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
Type 'PropsWithChildren<IInputProps>' is not assignable to type 'Pick<IInputProps, "key" | "accept" | "acceptCharset" | "action" | "allowFullScreen" | "allowTransparency" | "alt" | "as" | "async" | "autoComplete" | "autoFocus" | ... 348 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & RefAttributes<...>'.
    Type 'HTMLProps<HTMLInputElement> & { children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'RefAttributes<HTMLInputElement>'.
    Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
        Type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Ref<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Ref<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `HTMLProps` that extends `ClassAttributes` which define `ref` attribute as `LegacyRef` (`string | Ref<T> | undefined`).

On the opposite side you have `forwardRef` that returns a component for which the ref attribute is typed as `Ref<T> | undefined`.

So the ref attribute types are not compatible.

I recommend using:

```js
import React from 'react'

interface IInputProps extends React.ComponentProps<'input'> {}

const MyInput = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, IInputProps>((props, ref) => {
  return <input ref={ref} />;
});
```

And also I tend to avoid using `React.FunctionComponent<Props>` (see https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/function_components).